# Python code works in local but giving error "missing 1 required positional arguments : query" on Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-functions

I have python function which is running fine on my local system but the same function giving error on cloud function like "missing 1 required positional arguments : query".

I'm getting this error in cloud function from last Friday which is from 27/01/2023 before that function was working fine on cloud function.
And I also encountered that when I deploy any function new or old it started giving the above error and if any function which is deployed before the 27/01/2023 date it is working fine.

In python function I m using Sqlalchemy package to create connection with database and  I m passing like

```
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

url = URL(
    drivername="mysql+pymysql",
    username="user",
    password="1234",
    host="localhost",
    port=3306,
    database="db_1"
)
```

then it gives error like "missing 1 required positional arguments : query"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, 
in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, 
in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516,
in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502,   
in get_DBConn_new engine = conn.get_connection_new() File "DBConnDetails.py", line 13,
in get_connection_new database = const.database TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query'
```

Comment: Note that SQLAlchemy 2.0 was released on 2023-01-26. If your deploy installs the latest version then you must ensure that you have [migrated your code](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html).

Comment: I think Sqlalchemy is the issue here.I tried to  with previous version now and it is working. Thank You @snakecharmerb

Answer (score 1):

In SQLAlchemy 1.4 calling `URL()` directly emits an SADeprecationWarning if warnings are enabled:

```
>>> # SQLAlchemy 1.4
>>> url = URL(drivername='sqlite', username=None, password=None, host=None, port=None, database='foo.db')
<stdin>:1: SADeprecationWarning: Calling URL() directly is deprecated and will be disabled in a future release.  The public constructor for URL is now the URL.create() method.
```

As the warning suggests, you should use [URL.create](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create) instead:

```
>>> url = URL.create(
...     drivername="mysql+pymysql",
...     username="user",
...     password="1234",
...     host="localhost",
...     port=3306,
...     database="db_1"
... )
>>> url
mysql+pymysql://user:***@localhost:3306/db_1
```

This is partially documented in [The URL object is now immutable](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_14.html#the-url-object-is-now-immutable).